# Create a table with the same constraints,triggers,indexes, and statistics for house-keeping table

Tags: sql-server, scripting

I have a current database with few hundred tables, say, tables A,B,C... and I want to create the same tables with the same constraints,triggers,indexes, and stats as the original tables.

I know I could use generate script to do this but is there a faster way?

Do I have to rename the "new" tables with different names as well as their constraints,indexes etc?

Comment: Not that I know of. As for changing the table names, you can perform a substiution over the entire script changing `CREATE TABLE my_table` to `CREATE TABLE prefix_my_table` change `BLE ` (BLE + space to BLE + space + prefix). On*nix I'd use sed - doesn't windows have that these days?

Answer (score 1):

Right mouse click on your database -> Tasks -> Generate scripts -> Tables:

[image]

On the next page select if you want to generate a single file or single file per object and go to Advanced:

[image]

Here select constraints, triggers, indexes and what else you want to script

Comment: sepupic, is this the way to do it? I found another solution here, https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/65734/how-to-create-new-table-with-same-constraints-and-indexes Does both ways work as well?

Comment: @CookieMan The link you posted describes how to generate a script for ONE table. You asked how to generate it for ALL your tables. The option described there is applied to another context menu for single table script generation

Comment: @CookieMan - Also, of course (based on what seems like a follow-up question) using "Script Table as" -> "Create Table" does not appear to have an option to also script the data in the current table; it sounds like that's something you needed.